# Why the decline in search traffic for popular programming languages?

Tags: search

Is there any solid evidence behind the reasons for decline in search volume for popular programming languages?

Could this possibly be due to improvements in finding necessary information (no need to search 10 times to find something) and quality of information?

[image]

Comment: what's the source of your image?

Comment: @one - Myself, from Google trends

Comment: Rather than just 5 languages. Use the top 20 languages (see: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) What is the cumulative searches across these languages?

Comment: @Martin - The trend is the same when including all of the major languages. I picked 5 because it's easier to view. Besides java, php and javascript the rest are almost the same in terms of volume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of at least four factors that might be underway here:

1. As you say - resources are improving all the time, and less searching is required to find useful information
2. People search at specific sites more (such as stackoverflow) rather than a broader search through Google
3. People are searching for solutions which use specific frameworks/libraries which have grown (such as jquery rather than javascript, and drupal or zend rather than php)
4. People are adopting other languages - python and ruby, for example

Comment: Damn I was too slow in my answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

I think your point about the search engine queries being more precise might be the possible explanation.

Another one would be that people perhaps use this site or their favourite forum/site/blog to ask the "big questions".

One more reason, people are using paper books or ebooks with the information.

Interesting question